ESP32 online builded firmware can't boot
I tried to install nodemcu firmware to ESP32 C3 super mini board, with firmwares builded on https://nodemcu-build.com from dev-esp32-idf3-final branch.
After flashed, the serial console outputs very quickly:
invalid header: 0xffffffff
...
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffESP-ROM:esp32c3-api1-20210207
Build:Feb  7 2021
rst:0x7 (TG0WDT_SYS_RST),boot:0xf (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
Saved PC:0x40053f88
ffffffff

What i'm wrong?

is it built for C3?

First:
ESP32 is not binary compatible to ESP8266.
Therefor firmwares build for ESP8266 do not work with ESP32, therefor make sure you have the correct firmware type for your device.
Invalid header:0xffffffff looks like a clean/empty flash memory of the device.
Possible causes are:

problems during upload/flash of firmware (check you flash logs)
no bootloader was flashed, check the documentation for your firmware

